# fread into dynamically allocated buffer over 8 bytes failing

Tags: c, file-io, malloc, fread

I'm trying to read a file into memory using `fread`. From what I understand `fread` takes the buffer you want to write to, the size of each item you want to read in bytes, the number of items you want to read and then the file pointer.

I use `fseek` to find the file size used to allocate enough space in my data buffer to write into.

When I run the code I get a segfault and I am unsure why. This is the error I get:

```
./main
File Size: 786447
make: *** [Makefile:22: run] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This error happens on the line containing `fread` which makes me think it's not allocating enough memory but I've verified the file size. It seems like it should be large enough.

Below is my simple file io example that is having the segfault error.

**Test.c**

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

int readFile(const char* filename) {
    FILE* fp;
    int sz;
    uchar* data;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
        sz = ftell(fp);
        printf("File Size: %d\n", sz);
        rewind(fp);
        data = (uchar*)malloc(sz);
        fread(&data, sizeof(uchar), sz, fp);
        //later do things with data

        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I've noticed one really odd thing. I know `sizeof(data)` will give me `8` on my machine because it's the size of the pointer on a 64 bit machine. However if I read 8 or less bytes in fread it doesn't segfault.

So essentially on the line `fread(&data, sizeof(uchar), sz, fp);` if `sz >8` it seg faults.

At first, I thought maybe the problem was I was reading in too large of a file but surely you can read more than 8 bytes at a time right?

Comment: `fread(&data, sizeof(uchar), sz, fp);` `data` is already a pointer. Remove the & before it.

Comment: Thanks, @RetiredNinja, just out of curiosity, what was that actually doing? Trying to stick it at whatever address was in `data[0]`? Just trying to figure out why that seg faulted

Comment: If you had an int and wanted to read data into it you would pass the address of that int to fread, like &foo. A pointer is a variable too, so when you pass the address of it to fread you're reading data into it just like an int. That's why you could read 8 bytes into it because it is 8 bytes in length.